# Cannot remove anaconda environment

Tags: anaconda

I made a conda environment and now I want to delete it. I deactivated and made sure no processes were using it. I ran `conda env remove -n <name of env>` and no errors, but in my `C:/Users/Username/anaconda3/envs` I can still see it. I run `conda env remove --name <name of env> --all` and nothing happens. I can still `conda activate <name of env>` - what is happening here? Shall I just manually delete the directory? It looks like most has been removed, but the `Scripts` dir still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the Docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment)

You could try

```
conda remove --name <name of env> --all
```

and check with

```
conda info --envs
```

But it's also common practise to just delete the enviroment folder.